# Trying get headers angular

Tags: angular, header

I am new in Angular and I'm trying to get all the headers from a website(eg google.com). The purpose of this is analize the security of the fields. To do this I'm using the module HttpHeaders but I don't know if is the correct module to do this or maybe I've to change to another one. I'd follow the next steps:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpHeadersService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

I've this service, All the modules needed to do that were imported in the Angular module file, also I've a component where I call this service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHeadersService} from '../../services/http-headers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-form',
  templateUrl: './table-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-form.component.scss']
})
export class TableFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _httpHeadersService:HttpHeadersService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._httpHeadersService.getData());
  }

}
```

When I do that I get a Observable in the console but I don't know if I'm doing the correct process to get what I want because I don't see any field that show me in a clear way all the headers. I've to use another module? Could anybody make me any suggestion to achieve what I want?. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing `subscribe()`, unless you subscribe, your API call
   won't fire.
2. Then to get the response headers you need to observe response in the
   request, like: `get(url, {observe: 'response'})`
   https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#overload-9-2

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
       this._httpHeadersService.getData().subscribe(
           response => {console.log(response.headers)}
        );
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```html
this.httpClient.get(url, { observe: 'response'})
  .pipe(
    tap((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      console.log('response keys', response.headers.keys())
      console.log('content-disposition', response.headers.get('content-disposition'))
    })
   )
```